# Using if (!empty) on multiple variables but displaying content if one isn't empty

Tags: php, variables

I'm using the following

```
if (!empty($data['var_1']) 
 && !empty($data['var_2']) 
 && !empty($data['var_3']) 
 && !empty($data['var_4'])
 && !empty($data['var_5']) 
 && !empty($data['var_6']) 
 && !empty($data['var_7']) 
 && !empty($data['var_8']) 
 && !empty($data['var_9'])) {
//BLOCK HERE
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is if *all* of the variables are empty, hide the block. If 8 or less are empty, display the block.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: i m not getting ur question correctly.. can you please give some more idea

Comment: Can $var_x be an array, or are they entirely separate variables? Is this data from a form? A bit more background would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `||` not `&&`.  This will display the block only if they are all not empty.  I think there is probably a nicer way to do this, though, like `array_filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just use a loop and an `$isok` variable:

```
$isok = false;
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {
    if( !empty($data['var_'.$i])) {
        $isok = true;
        break; // no need to continue looping
    }
}
if( $isok) {
    // BLOCK HERE
}
```

This is easier to edit too, in case you change the `var_` part or want a different range of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
$data = array_filter($data); // remove all empty value form array

if (count($data)) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote will display the block if ALL of the variables aren't empty. If you want it to be displayed when ANY of the variable isn't empty, use OR instead of AND by replacing the `&&` by `||`.

```php
<?php
if (!empty($data['var_1']) || !empty($data['var_2']) || !empty($data['var_3']) || !empty($data['var_4']) || !empty($data['var_5']) || !empty($data['var_6']) || !empty($data['var_7']) || !empty($data['var_8']) || !empty($data['var_9'])) {
    //BLOCK HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**array_values()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) for that:

```
if ( count(array_values($data)) ) {
    //BLOCK HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace && (AND) with || (OR)

```
if (!empty($data['var_1']) 
 || !empty($data['var_2']) 
 || !empty($data['var_3']) 
 || !empty($data['var_4'])
 || !empty($data['var_5']) 
 || !empty($data['var_6']) 
 || !empty($data['var_7']) 
 || !empty($data['var_8']) 
 || !empty($data['var_9'])) {
//BLOCK HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty(array_values($data))) { /* will return you true if all variables are empty*/}
```